# Prevent groff form setting bigger whitespace after sentence

Tags: groff

Is there a way to prevent that groff is setting more whitespace after each sentence? (Not on a per sentence basis, but in general.)

Comment: Please provide an example and the command you compile with so we can reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input lines which end with `.`, and input with `.` followed by two spaces in the middle of a line will generate an extra *sentence space* after the `.` and the word space. This is controlled in groff with the `.ss` command. Some macro packages have their own command too; for example with the `mom` macros it is `.SS`.

So to reduce it to a mimimum you can use

```
.ss 12 0
```

The first number is the inter-word space (see `man groff_diff`). With `mom` you can use

```
.SS 0
```